# Why the value couldn't show in the view after communicate between two controllers?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I met this problem again.Could anybody help me with this?

the first view:

```
<a type="button" ui-sref="index.usermng.userInfo" ng-click="checkUserInfo(item.id)" class="btn btn-primary">CheckUser</a>
```

the first controller:

```
 $scope.checkUserInfo = function(userId) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('toUserInfo', userId);
}
```

the second view:

```
<div class="tab-pane active tab-chrome" id="tab-chrome">
    <div class="row feature">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">UserId：{{data.user.userId}}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Name：{{data.user.name}}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Sex：{{data.user.sex}}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Birthday：{{data.user.birthday | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Mobile：{{data.user.mobile}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the second controller:

```
userApp.controller('userInfoCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', 'serverUrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, serverUrl) {
$rootScope.$on('toUserInfo', function(event, userId) {
    console.log(userId); //i can get userId here
    $http.get(serverUrl + "/user/info?userId=" + userId).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data); // i can get data here
        //if (data.code == 0) {
        //    $scope.detailUserID = userId;
        //    $scope.detailUserName = data.data.user.name;
        //    $scope.detailSex = data.data.user.sex;
        //    $scope.detailBirthday = data.data.user.birthday;
        //    $scope.detailMobile = data.data.user.mobile;
        //    $scope.detailCash = data.data.accumulate.usableCash;
              $scope.data = data.data
        }
        //can't show in the view
    })
})
```

}])

the config:

```
.state('index.usermng.userInfo',{
        url: '/userInfo',
        templateUrl: 'tpls/userInfo.html',
        controller: 'userInfoCtrl'
    })
```

In the second controller,I can get userId from the first controller,and I can get the data,but the view shows nothing,where is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your if block condition passes? What happens when you log $scope at the end of that if block?

Comment: @MattHerbstritt yes,it can pass

Answer (score 2):

This is a well known pitfall of Angular. It has to do with the fact that in the template the value is not updated because the scope variables are passed as values and that happens only once, when your view is rendered. That is normal Javascript behaviour.

The way around it is to place all the values on an object. I suggest you do this in your controller:

`$scope.data = data.data`

and in your templates you change it like this:

`<li class="list-group-item">Name：{{data.user.name}}</li>`

and so on

A good rule of thumb here is: if there is no dot in the variable in the template, then there is something wrong.

BTW, a more favourable approach is to use controllerAs, which forces you to use a dot in variable names in the template

Comment: thanks,I do it as you suggested,but it's not working.

Comment: @ParkerSong can you show me the updated version of it?

Comment: I just updated it.I think the problem is the ui-router,if I put the two views into the same view,the data can show.but if I create a new html file as the second view,the data can't show

Comment: still can't resolve this problem,could help me with this?